# .net Core 3.1 Newtonsoft.Json converts dictionary<int,string> key to string

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net

My custom object's one of properties is dictionary and I need to convert whole object to json string but JsonConvert changes dictionary key from Int to String which is what I don't want to happen.

```
var test = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    [1] = "2"
};

var jsonDictionary = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, Formatting.None);

// output {"1":"2"}
```

My desired output should be `{ 1 : "2" }`

Comment: Integer keys aren't supported in JSON.

Comment: But if I am doing KeyValuPair<int,string> then it works  ?

Comment: @Haytam Any solution how to solve it ? I mean should I  use string key and on back-end convert to int  ?

Comment: Show evidence of KeyValuePair working on a site like https://dotnetfiddle.net/, because that would be a bug.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yeah, you  are right I re-tested and totally forgot "key"  word being added..

Anyway, do   you have any ideas on my  question then ?

Comment: There is no solution to this, your keys will need to be strings in order for the JSON to be valid and "parse-able". Why do you need your keys to be integers?

Comment: The solution is either use an array (e.g., `[ , "2"]`) which has numeric indexes, or cope with strings. The real question is whether the output you've received can be deserialized to the type you expect. In other words, does `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, string>>(jsonDictionary)` work?

Comment: ok, now I do understand, will just simply   go with a string key and  work with it,  just wanted to avoid conversions if possible.

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm hoping this might clear things up a little and hope it helps! When we call Json.SerializeObject we're saying "take my object and turn it into a string representation so that I can (for example) transmit my object over HTTP".

But when you deserialize the string representation, everything goes back to the original types. It's not so much that you can "avoid conversion" but what happens is Json does the conversion automatically so we don't have to.

One thing you might consider trying, that will give you very fine control over this process, is to make a custom class like so:

```
class CustomDictionary : Dictionary<int, string> { }
```

Then the "round trip" serialize/deserialize puts you back to an object where the Key is truly an int and only the Value is a string:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CustomDictionary myDict = new CustomDictionary();
        myDict[1] = "Two";
        string stringRepresentation = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDict);
        Console.WriteLine(stringRepresentation); // looks like {"1":"Two"}

        // Now it's back to normal Dictionary<int, string>
        CustomDictionary deserializedDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomDictionary>(stringRepresentation);
    }
```

Comment: I am happy to see such nice explanation. ! 

Thanks !

Comment: So glad I could help!